# Updating the position of a ConnectionPatch in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt4

I am using a matplotlib widget within a PyQt4 GUI application. On a figure, I am using ConnectionPatches in order to draw lines. I keep references to them as such:

```
self.x_axis1 = ConnectionPatch((0, yPos), (xPos-boxWidth/2, yPos), coordsA='data', edgecolor='w', linewidth=linewidth)
self.x_axis2 = ConnectionPatch((xPos+boxWidth/2, yPos), (cursorX, yPos), coordsA='data', edgecolor='w', linewidth=linewidth)
self.y_axis1 = ConnectionPatch((xPos, 0), (xPos, yPos-boxHeight/2), coordsA='data', edgecolor='w', linewidth=linewidth)
self.y_axis2 = ConnectionPatch((xPos, yPos+boxHeight/2), (xPos, cursorY), coordsA='data', edgecolor='w', linewidth=linewidth)
```

...and add them to the figure in the typical way:

```
self.ui.mpl_right.axes.add_patch(self.x_axis1)
self.ui.mpl_right.axes.add_patch(self.x_axis2)
self.ui.mpl_right.axes.add_patch(self.y_axis1)
self.ui.mpl_right.axes.add_patch(self.y_axis2)
```

According to the matplotlib documentation, you can set the position of them as such:

```
self.x_axis1.set_positions((0, yPos), (xPos-boxWidth/2, yPos))
self.x_axis2.set_positions((xPos+boxWidth/2, yPos), (cursorX, yPos))
self.y_axis1.set_positions((xPos, 0), (xPos, yPos-boxHeight/2))
self.y_axis2.set_positions((xPos, yPos+boxHeight/2), (xPos, cursorY))
```

Typically, you would just call draw() on the figure's canvas like so to get objects to update:

```
self.ui.mpl_right.figure.canvas.draw()
```

...but this does absolutely nothing at all.

Currently, I am just removing them and re-adding them all over again using remove():

```
self.x_axis1.remove()
self.x_axis2.remove()
self.y_axis1.remove()
self.y_axis2.remove()
```

Is there any way to update the position of a ConnectionPatch without having to destroy them completely and re-adding them all over again?

Comment: I am also interested in an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

the trick is to use '**xy1**' and '**xy2**' attributes instead of '**set_positions()**' as you did. So, if you put:

```
self.x_axis1.xy1 = (0, yPos)
self.x_axis1.xy2 = (xPos-boxWidth/2, yPos)
```

instead of:

```
self.x_axis1.set_positions((0, yPos), (xPos-boxWidth/2, yPos))
```

it should work.